# Why are there 3 cronjobs that needs to be added to crontab

Tags: cron, magento2.2.6

Starting from the official documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#create-the-magento-crontab

Somewhere in there is this... that gets added to crontab

```
#~ MAGENTO START
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END
```

There are 3 things that get executed every minute.
What's the difference between `cron:run`, `cron.php` and  `setup:cron:run` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between cron:run and setup:cron:run](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182203/difference-between-cronrun-and-setupcronrun)

Comment: @MagenX, Marius have the query about `magento2/update/cron.php`

Comment: @MagenX the question is not a duplicate. The one you mention asks for difference between 2 lines. Mine has something extra.

Comment: With Magent 2.4 it is only a single line, not three. See [Configure and run cron](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

magento requires to run 1 + 2,3 cron tasks:

1 - `cron:run`  = indexer and scheduled tasks

2 - `setup:cron:run` = Web Setup Wizard + Component Manager

3 - `update/cron.php` = System Upgrade

Comment: i guess creating so many cronjobs was overlooked by magento engineers...

Comment: What If I don't use the setup wizard and I don't need to run system upgrades on a regular basis? Can I just use `cron:run`.

Comment: sure you can run any cronjobs you need